# Data Points Not Visible When Using CustomLabel

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm trying to produce a chart that shows data points for each hour of the last 24 hours using the .Net Chart Control (`System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting`). I want the X-axis to have two rows, the top row showing the hour in the format "8PM" (`"htt"`) and the bottom row showing the date in the form of "07/16" (`"MM\\/dd"`). The problem with my code below is the custom label does not show up unless I uncomment the two lines that have been commented out. But, when I do, the data points disappear. What's going on? How can I show the data points and the custom label?

As a side question, I don't understand why I have to add 2 to the `DayOfYear` on the `AxisX.Maximum`. Seems like it should be that I have to add 1.

```
chart1.Series.Clear();
var series = chart1.Series.Add("Trend");
series.XValueMember = "Date";
series.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
series.YValueMembers = "Count";
series.YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
series.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
series.MarkerSize = 16;
series.BorderWidth = 10;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 0;
//chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear;
//chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear + 2;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "htt";
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -60;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(1, DateTimeIntervalType.Days, "MM\\/dd", 1, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark);
```

Here's what the chart looks like when the two lines are commented out. Notice the custom label does not show up.

[image: When lines are commented out]

And here's what the chart looks like when the two lines are uncommented. Notice that the data points are missing, but the custom label for the day shows up.

[image: When lines are uncommented]

Comment: What charting library are you using?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Comment: @JoeWhite, jstreet is correct. I updated the question to list specifically which chart control I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a chart below similar to your description:

[image]

In order to do that the Minimum and Maximum were set as follows:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = DateTime.Now.ToOADate();
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24).ToOADate();
```

So, if you change the way Minimum and Maximum are set, it should display your custom labels along with data points all together.

EDIT 1:
Ok, now i managed to get a custom label like yours, setting the Minimum and Maximum as described before:

[image]:

For practical purposes of "X-Axis arithmetic", like setting Minimum and Maximum, you need to use `ToOADate()` which returns a floating-point representing number of days before/after December 30 1899 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); as `DayOfYear` retuns an integer and it is inappropriate in such situation.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly, though I had to use `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24).ToOADate();` for the `Minimum` so it would yesterday and today.